# Codable Algorithm to the generalised Complex Schur Decomposition without using Inbuilt functions

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition, schur-decomposition

So i have been looking online for a proper algorithm from scratch which solves the complex generalised Eigen Value problem for **low rank non invertible square matrices**. I am aware about the generalised Schur Decomposition Approach but cannot find a programmable algorithm for the same. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can try the Francis QR algorithm (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm ) but it works only for real matrices and does not converge in all cases.

Comment: I tried the QR ALgorithm with certain optimisations to make it converge for practical complex matrices. Got the methods from Dr Strang's MIT Course on Applications of linear algebra